# CSS/HTML Is there a way to prevent scrolling when lineheight:1 is too small to fit?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to use `line-height:1` for vertical alignment reasons, but some fonts require larger line heights than so.

When `line-height:1` is set on such fonts, a text area will automatically become scrollable.

Is there a way to prevent this **beyond** hiding the scroll or set **`overflow:hidden`**?

I'd like this to work globally and I do not like to set `overflow:hidden` globally.

Comment: Can you provide an example? If you only need vertical alignment of an object (e.g. a div with your font) you can also try to set the parent container to display:table and the objects that container to display:table-cell and vertical-align:middle - see https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: So you want the same result as **overflow:hidden** without using **overflow:hidden**?

Comment: Also why do you not like the set **overflow:hidden** globally? It is accepted by all browsers from a pretty early stage. GC 1.0, IE 4.0, FF 1.0, Safari 1.0 and Opera 7.0

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide more details.

Comment: Just give a class to fonts and set overflow hidden so that it's not set globally...

Comment: @Mike It's not just about centering in a special case. I think i found the issue though, it seems to be a bug in some browsers, when overflow-x:hidden is used. See this example in Chrome: http://jsbin.com/yimemirige/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Do you see how the browser introduces a scrollbar? Even if you hide it, you can still scroll the elements.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you don't want to use `overflow:hidden` on those specific divs rather than `overflow-x`.

Comment: because I would be solving a problem that shouldn't exist. But if you must know I overflow-y:hidden it will cut characters if lineheight is too small for font.